# CGAL cmake on cygwin fails

Tags: cmake, cygwin, cgal

I'm trying to compile CGAL 4.5 on cygwin (windows 7). i have gcc-core, gcc-g++ and gmp installed but when i try to run cmake i get following error:

```
$ cmake .
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/metalab/CGAL-4.5/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/metalab/CGAL-4.5/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/Platform/CYGWIN.cmake:15 (message):
  CMake no longer defines WIN32 on Cygwin!

  (1) If you are just trying to build this project, ignore this warning or
  quiet it by setting CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0 in your environment or in
  the CMake cache.  If later configuration or build errors occur then this
  project may have been written under the assumption that Cygwin is WIN32.
  In that case, set CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1 instead.

  (2) If you are developing this project, add the line

    set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0) # Remove when CMake >= 2.8.4 is required

  at the top of your top-level CMakeLists.txt file or set the minimum
  required version of CMake to 2.8.4 or higher.  Then teach your project to
  build on Cygwin without WIN32.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/metalab/CGAL-4.5/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeRCCompiler.cmake
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:40 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".cxx" for file

    /home/metalab/CGAL-4.5/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:

    C CXX RC

  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

i already tried playing with CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 but no success.

Comment: Did you try compiling a trivial hello-world with the compiler c++.exe? Maybe you need to install more cygwin packages for it to really work.

Comment: yes i did and it works. in fact i already used the cygwin installation to compile libxml++ aswell.

Comment: try `make VERBOSE=1` to see why cmake says you CXX compiler is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in a similar error. cmake seemed to not be able to find anything from Cygwin.

The fact is that you need to run the Cygwin version of cmake. If you installed cmake from an installer and it went under `C:\Program Files`, you have the wrong cmake and it won't find most everything which it should otherwise find.